# mySql workbench fails to launch

Tags: 16.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

I've used `mysql-workbench` command to launch mysql workbrench but an error message appeared:

```
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib11VariantTypeD1Ev
```

Any suggestion or workaround to get the workbench running would be great!

Answer (score 2):

I just installed the latest updates to 16.04 LTS and I have mysql-workbench working. I had mysql-server installed already and added now mysql-workbench as new. I have these versions:

```
mysql-workbench 6.3.6i+dfsg-0ubuntu1
mysql-server 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
```

MySQL Workbench's Help > About shows 6.3.6 build 511 CE (64 bits)
My kernel is `4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP x86_64`

Try listing the dependencies of `libgiomm-2.4.so.1` and checking if any of them are missing:

```
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1
```

You can also try ldd for `/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin`, but it produces a lot bigger list and I think your error message refers to a dependency of `libgiomm-2.4`.

I prefer using `synaptic` to update software. I would run the command synaptic from the terminal, use Reload, Mark All Upgrades and Apply, reboot if a new kernel was installed. If you don't want to use Mark All Upgrades, use Reload, then click Search and search for mysql-workbench, select mysql-workbench with right mouse button and select Mark for Upgrade, and do the same to mysql-workbench-data, and then click Apply.

If it doesn't find updates, try selecting mysql-workbench, select Reinstallation for it with right mouse button, do the same for mysql-workbench-data, and then click Apply.

You can also try Mark for Complete Removal, Apply, and then install it as a new package.

If you prefer apt, you can try first to check for broken dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

I would also first update packages to the latest ones. It should also install updates to mysql-workbench if it finds any:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Reboot if a new kernel was installed.

If there were no updates and/or mysql-workbench still doesn't work, try removing it with autoremove so any new libs installed as dependencies are also removed:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove mysql-workbench
```

Then try installing it again:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed workbench from the deb package at the mysql site, I believe it is buggy... I did, and it wouldn't start as well.

Here is what I did:

Remove the installed version:
If you try `apt remove mysql-workbench` it may say the package is not installed.

Just run:

```
apt -f install
```

This should fix the broken dependencies. To check if it was removed, run:

```
ll /user/lib/
```

And it should **NOT** list a directory named `mysql-workbench`

Then just install from the official repo

```
apt install mysql-workbench
```

---

Please note:

- I am not a Linux expert
- Commands listed above may need **sudo** permissions
- Using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled mysqlworkbench

```
sudo apt remove mysql-workbench
```

then i downloaded package from official website[hear](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). After that i installed with bellow command

```
dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

after that i run

```
mysql-workbench
```

although it is contrary to what other people suggest that install using apt or apt-get but that not worked and this thing worked for me.